# PlayFramework 1.x routes with classic query delimiters

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-1.x, query-string

In my routes:

```
GET /rest/trafficstats?{usr}&{pwd}        Controller.trafficstats
```

In my controllers:

```
 public static void trafficstats(String usr, String pwd) { ..
```

Does not work if I go by this ur:

```
http://localhost:9000/rest/trafficstats?usr=usr2&pwd=pwd
```

returns: **404**

Why?

The deal is with the second param (pwd)..  I should not use "&"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the url template without parameters at all, like:

GET /rest/trafficstats.

So when you do /rest/trafficstats?usr=usr&pwd=pass play will automatically bind your arguments